# How might I import IIS handler mappings from another IIS instance on a different machine?

Tags: powershell, iis, powershell-remoting, iis-handlers

I'm migrating from one computer to another and in order to serve up my web app locally IIS requires some handler mappings in order to serve `.svc` extensions. I found on the new computer I'm missing those mappings. I'd like to script the creation of these mappings so that it's reliably repeatable. I found there's a powershell command `Get-WebHandler` and `New-WebHandler`. I was hoping I could *get* the hanlder mappings from the remote (old) IIS instance and pipe that into the *new* hanlder command.

Can I reference a remote IIS machine with `Get-WebHandler` or is there another command I would use to get IIS settings that I would then pipe into `Get-WebHandler`?

Answer (score 1):

The `*-WebHandler` cmdlets don't work against a remote server, so you can not pipe existing handlers into `New-WebHandler`.

There are some hacks you can do:

- Copy the  node from ApplicationHost.config on the old server to the new server.
- Get the output from `Get-WebHandler` into a csv file. Use that file to create new handlers on using `New-WebHandler`. This requires some coding.
- Create a PowerShell script from scratch to create your custom handlers with `New-WebHandler`. You could use pipe the output of `Get-WebHandler` from both servers into a text-file and do a Diff, so you can find what is different.
- Move custom handlers into the web.config of your site and the copy the site.